# MSBUILD : cordova-build error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: cordova, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

This is not a runtime error but a build error in the following configuration

Windows 10 version 1511,(swedish)
Visual studio 2015 Community update 3
Cordova tools for Visual studio version 6.1.1
AngularJs 1.5.8

The error only arises when trying to build for 'Windows AnyCPU' or Windows Phone universal not for the other platforms.I suspect that it is the angular object which is undefined but I'm not sure of this. The only information is Line 1 and Col 1 but not in what file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Will be this explanation of this issue enough to answer your question? Don't hesitate to add some code

Comment: Enabling verbose output in VS can help: http://sedodream.com/2008/06/16/ChangingBuildVerbosityInVisualStudio.aspx

Comment: thanks for your comment but unfortunately it didn't give me any clue about the error.

Answer (score 1):

Because I walked right into it; In VS2015(and assumable everywhere else) if you have a blank domain access rule, it will trigger it.  NOTE: same goes for the XML [image]