# cordova build for Android fails from VS but not from console

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing a Cordova app for Android and iOS with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and recently I am having some problems building for Android (iOS builds work fine).

When I build from Visual Studio I get the following error (I am using diagnostic MSBuild output, but this is all that is shown related to the error, towards the end of the log).

```
1>                     No scripts found for hook "before_compile". (TaskId:25)
1>                     ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk (TaskId:25)
1>                     JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\ (TaskId:25)
1>                     Reading build config file: C:\apprep\build.json (TaskId:25)
1>16:58:37.536     1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : TypeError: undefined is not a function
1>                     TypeError undefined is not a function (TaskId:25)
1>                   Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:25)
```

However, if I run the command `cordova build android` from the command prompt it works well.

I am using Cordova 7.0.1, Node 6.11.0, npm 3.10.10, Java 1.8.0.131.

I have tried countless solutions to this problem (uninstalling and reinstalling tools and modules, cache cleaning, etc. etc.). I cannot figure what is wrong with the Visual Studio tools for Cordova. Can I find additional logging somewhere that could help me realize where is this `undefine is not a function` error coming from?

Comment: is this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084692/msbuild-cordova-build-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-indexof-of-und applicable to you?

Comment: is your build successful if you do it via. cordova CLI?

Comment: I do not have empty domains in the list. Besides, my error is different. It sais `undefine is not a function`. And yes, when I run `cordova build android` from the command prompt it works well, as I already mentioned.

Comment: Some problems that I have with Cordova and VS, I fix just deleting the platforms folder. VS will recreate it automatically when you build.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root cause is that your version of Node is too low. I hit this trying to run through a MSVC Cordova tutorial on push notifications. MSVC defaults to an ancient Node release like v0.11.16. But one of the plugins they tell you use in the tutorial has been updated and now requires a higher version of the Android platform, which required a newer version of Node (the default LTS release v6.11.0 worked fine for me).

1. Uninstall any old versions of Node.
2. Install the LTS version of Node (v6.11.0 when I wrote this) at https://nodejs.org/en/download/.
3. Restart Windows (really, I encountered one situation where a process or daemon was hanging onto a cached proxy version of node somehow that would have prevented it from being deleted like it was supposed to).
4. Open cmd.exe and type `where node.exe`, ensure that the path to your v6.11.0 release comes first. If not modify your PATH and restart.
5. In MSVC under Options -> Projects and Solutions -> External Web Tools add the path to your 6.11.0 version of node.exe to the top of
   the list. (all docs tell you to do this but it may not be necessary, at least mine built fine without it).
6. In MSVC under Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Cordova Tools disable "Use a sandboxed version of NodeJS".
7. In MSVC under Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Cordova Tools choose "Clear Cordova Cache".

**NOTE:** instructions 8-11 are recommended if you update from v5 to v6 of Cordova (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29990937/2448947)

8. In the console type `npm install -g cordova@X.Y.Z` to install (where X.Y.Z is the cordova CLI version you chose in your project's config.xml) to ensure the new version of Node has Cordova installed.
9. Update your platform with `cordova platform update android`.
10. In the directory of your project, run `cordova plugin list`.
11. For each plugin listed in (10), run `cordova plugin remove <X>` AND `cordova plugin add <X>` to reinstall the plugin.
12. Ensure you see "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" running `cordova build android` from the console.
13. Verify the build works in MSVC as well.

You can now easily repro the "TypeError undefined is not a function" bug by turning "Use a sandboxed version of NodeJS" back on in the MSVC settings and rebuilding. Therefore the root cause must be due to an obsolete release of NodeJS.

---

My favorite thing about this is how the software community attempted to solve the DLL Hell problem with half a dozen different incompatible package managers that are now constantly conflicting with each other.